# Ideal height for placing indoor split AC unit?

Tags: cooling

This is an indoor air conditioner unit of split-unit type.  It has the compressor outside (usually on the roof), and the indoor looks like this:

[image]

***The question:*** How to determine the ideal height of such units?

E.g. should it be closest possible to the ceiling?  Or should we intentionally leave a distance?  How to determine the distance?

Comment: It's normal to leave a small space to provide easy access to the unit and clearance for removing the cowl. And the instructions will give recommendations or minimum clearances for adequate air flow. The other main considerations are routing the refrigerant line, running wires, and perhaps hanging deadwood and patching the wall.

Comment: @PhilSweet - So, generally if routing pipes is not an issue, should we place the inside unit generally as high as possible, except for leaving like 5 inch gap below the ceiling?

Comment: away from floor should produce the most even effect on the floor.  The most even is at infinity where you experience 0 effect from the unit.  Figure out a balance between affecting a small area a lot and affecting a wide area a little.  Insulation is something to consider as well - better insulation can let you get a more even effect at the expense of time.

Comment: Not over the cook top. :)